# Zap2Docker custom scan rules

Tags: docker, zap

I'm trying to find a way to write my own OWASP zap scan rule for the purpose of running a baseline scan using zap2docker's **baseline_scan.py** and define the rule severity (info/warn/fail) in the docker config file specified by "-c"

When going through the ZAP repository, I have found source file of a rule e.g. [10055](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/main/addOns/pscanrules/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/pscanrules/ContentSecurityPolicyScanRule.java) and would like to create a similar thing, only in a way that I would not be forced to create my own docker image and could load this rule from within the CI/CD pipeline.

Is there any way to **create a custom ZAP rule** and **run it as part of the baseline_scan with defined severity?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes ... but it might be non trivial.
You have a couple of options:

1. Write a new ZAP add-on containing your rule and copy it into the right place in the docker image before starting your scan
2. Write a script passive scan rule and configure ZAP to load it on start

For more help doing either of these things the ZAP User Group is the best place to ask: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users